# How to open a drawer in flutter test

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I am trying to test a custom drawer but find it hard opening it in the test, tried the following to begin with and even this test doesn't pass. The error is: `Bad state: no element`.

```
void main() {
  testWidgets('my drawer test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    final displayName = "displayName";
    var drawKey = UniqueKey();
    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(key: drawKey, child: Text(displayName),),
    )));
    await tester.tap(find.byKey(drawKey));
    expect(find.text(displayName), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're calling `tap()` on the `Drawer`, but it isn't in view as it's hidden on the left. Because of this, the `Finder` doesn't find any elements and the `tap()` is unsuccessful. And even if the `Finder` found the `Drawer`, tapping on the `Drawer` itself doesn't open it anyway.

One way, and in my opinion, the simplest way of doing it is to provide a `GlobalKey` for the `Scaffold` and call `openDrawer()` on the current `State` of it. You could also tap on the hamburger icon or swipe from the left - but calling `openDrawer()` is more deterministic:

```dart
void main() {
  testWidgets('my drawer test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    const displayName = "displayName";

    await tester.pumpWidget(
      MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          key: scaffoldKey,
          drawer: const Text(displayName),
        ),
      ),
    );

    scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
    await tester.pump();

    expect(find.text(displayName), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can grab the top left of the parent widget and use dragFrom in order to simulate opening the drawer. In comparison to the current accepted answer, this does not require you to pass the scaffold key.

An example with a slight modification of the original code:

```
testWidgets('my drawer test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  final displayName = "displayName";
  var drawKey = UniqueKey();
  await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(key: drawKey, child: Text(displayName),),
    )));

  await tester.dragFrom(tester.getTopLeft(find.byType(MaterialApp)), Offset(300, 0));
  await tester.pumpAndSettle();

  expect(find.text(displayName), findsOneWidget);
});
```

Notice tester.pumpAndSettle() was added to ensure enough time has passed.

Answer (score 3):

**another solution:**

```
  final ScaffoldState state = tester.firstState(find.byType(Scaffold));
  state.openDrawer();
  await tester.pump();
  await tester.tap(find.byTooltip('your tooltip text'));
  await tester.pump();
```